# Regular expression to select substring using position value

Tags: regex, string, position

I would like to select a substring using position

Example: `201967895678`

I need to write regex to select a element from position 5 to 8

I am new to regex and kindly help me to figure it out.

Comment: The regex can also follow this pattern : 4 digits after 2019.so if input is 2019675890 then the output is 6758 and example2 : 2019557445 then output is 5574

Comment: It make no sense to get position 5 to 8 ... What if you have a Number with 20 positions and the next Number have 25? 
To get the position 5 to 8 use your programming language.

Comment: Here in my examples the first 4 digits represents a year so i need to pick the next 4 digits after the year

Comment: Here in my examples the first 4 digits represents a year so i need to pick the next 4 digits after the year

Answer (score 2):

`/^.{4}(.{4})/` will match the positions 5 to 8 of a string.

Explanation:

`^` matches the start of the string

`.{4}` matches the characters 1 to 4 and

`(.{4})` will match and capture the characters 5 to 8!